How to work around the lack of device tree on amd64 arch?
I have a mainboard with several I2C, SPI and I2S devices.  It's a mainboard with a CPU/RAM daughterboard.
I'm currently using arm64 CPUs (iMX8M).  I let the kernel drivers know about the I2C addresses and GPIOs using the device tree.
If I switch to an amd64 architecture CPU, how do I tell the kernel drivers which I2C addresses and GPIOs to use?  (amd64 does not use device tree.)
